# What versions do templates and TBBs run against?

Tags: publishing, cme, templating, session

In at least SDL Tridion 2011, Content Manager Explorer and Template Builder run against the current, even if minor, version of a template. Publishing will use the last major, checked-in, template version.

**For Template Building Blocks (TBBs):**

How do the following [publishing contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14642317/395495)* affect TBB versions?

- Template Builder
- CME Preview
- Session Preview
- Publish

*This would mainly be for DWT TBBS and C# TBB fragments. I'm not sure how we'd create a minor version of a TBB that's part of an assembly (it that possible with `TcmUploadAssembly`?).*

**For Session Preview**

Also, which version of a template should Session Preview use?

**Background**: in older versions of Tridion, we had to *check in* (at least) legacy templates to see changes in CME Preview (update, Save & Close, then see changes). Now we can simply Save then check, but I'm not sure for XPM... yet (update follows). :-)

**Update:** Changing markup in a DWT without publishing *does* show in Session Preview. If viewing as the user that made the DWT edit, I see the latest template, even if it's a minor version. However, viewing as another user, I only see the last major version.

*In other words, if viewing the page as the same user, we can edit a DWT, save, and then immediately see changes in Experience Manager's Session Preview without checking in.* Feel free to clarify or add more; I'll also this as a community answer.

Comment: You're right, it's not possible to create a minor version of an assembly *with TcmUploadAssembly*, but it's possible to check out the item in the CME, upload a new version and hit "Save", so your question is indeed relevant there too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experience Manager's Session Preview is similar to Template Builder and CME Preview in at least two ways:

- **`PreviewDynamic`**. All have "`RenderMode.PreviewDynamic`" and can run without being published/deployed. Be wary if using just this value for CME-specific "Preview" code.
- **See edits quickly**. Just like Template Builder and Preview, we don't have to *Check In* changes to test updates. For example, saving a DWT will make the changes visible in the next Session Preview update, if made by the same user.

When developing Session Preview code, we should keep in mind the fact that **both content and TBBs are session-based to specific users** (users will see variations based on who owns what and what's checked in).

We should of course still publish to get changes to Staging's markup.